# Unable to compile STL with templates

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, list, stl

I am having some problems trying to get this template to compiles, I think the problem is with the Edge class, I happily compiled before I added it.

Firstly this is supposed to model a weighted connected graph. Each graph has a graph has a collection of all of the nodes in the systems, and each Node is a template which holds the node value of type T (I have tested it with int and char) and a list of the Edges, edges are the connections to the other nodes, and has a weighting and pointer the other node.

When I had just a list of nodes (in graph) it compiled fine and all was well. then When I added Edges part it just doesn't compile. Could it be that templates just doesn't like it when 1 refers to one which in turn points back?

I get the following errors: (there are a few others but I am sure they are just error carried forward)

> C4430: missing type specifier - int
> assumed. Note: C++ does not support
> default-int edge.cpp 12
>
> error C2974: 'std::list' : invalid
> template argument for '_Ty', type
> expected node.cpp 13
>
> error C2065: 'Edge' : undeclared
> identifier node.cpp 13

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if there is any more info I can provide just ask.

```
#ifndef GRAPH_CPP
#define GRAPH_CPP

#include "Node.cpp"
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Graph
{
private:
    list< Node<T>* > nodes;
    //bool (*compare) (T, T);
public:
    Graph(){}
    void addNodes(T nNode)
    {
        nodes.push_back( new Node<T>( nNode ) );
    }
};
#endif


#ifndef NODE_CPP
#define NODE_CPP

#include <vector>
#include "Edge.cpp"

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Node
{
private:
    list< Edge < T > > adjacencies;
    T value;
public:
    Node(T nVal)
    {
        value = nVal;
    }
    T getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
};
#endif //NODE_CPP


#ifndef EDGE_CPP
#define EDGE_CPP

#include "Node.cpp"

template <typename T>
class Edge
{
private:
    Node<T>* node;
public:
    Edge(){}
};

#endif
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to include .cpp files?

Comment: How are you instantiating everything?

Comment: you should NEVER include cpp files ... include header files instead...

Comment: I think he's treating CPP files as header files.

Comment: There is nothing technically wrong with #including .cpp files, as long as they are not included for compilation in your build, but it is very unusual, and patently confusing.

Comment: **Do not** put `using namespace std;` at global namespace in a header file. **Do not** include implementation files in header files, like your `#include "Node.cpp"` don't do that. **Do not** call header files [something.cpp].

Comment: Hi, sorry if my code has offended anyone, I will take on board what you have said, just I haven't really found a clean way to layout templates, you are right about the namespace though, I'll remove the includes.

Comment: If you want to include implementation for header templates a "normal" convention is to name them name.inl or name_inl.h. Although it is only a convention, it is very important to stick with conventions to make code understandable by others.

Comment: "do not include .cpp files" Spoken many times by people who never work with templates.

Answer (score 0):

I think a forward declaration of Edge will fix that before your Node declaration.

```
template <typename T>
class Edge;
```

You may need to do the same thing for Edge with Node.

Comment: Yeah.  You'll probably need to do the same thing in the Edge file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer I am just going to try it, this would be written in the Node file? Like specifying functions in C?

Comment: Yes.  But you should do what a lot of the comments have suggested and rename your files to .h (header) files.  You should also do what they've suggested and NOT use using namespace std;

Comment: If in a non inline example, should I declare the class in the header or the source file. Also is it good practice to declare all the class I use in each source file, regardless to whether the compiler can suss it out? thanks again

Comment: Yes you declare the class in the header file.  Then you declare the non-inline / template methods in the cpp (implementation file).

Answer (score 0):

Node and Edge are tightly coupled. Edge should probably be "complete" first as Node has `list<Edge>` so I am not sure if Edge can be forwardly declared at that point. Edge has Node * so it definitely can be.

```
template< typename T > class Node;

template< typename T > class Edge
{
 // define
};

template< typename T> class Node
{
 // define
};
```